# Remove, delete or turn null specific elements in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, splice

I'm trying to utilize splice to create a copy of an array with the elements from a certain position determined by the position of the current cell in a spreadsheet and pass those on to the splice function to remove the elements from a specified position to the end of the array.
E.g. if the current column is in the 6th row and 4th column, all elements in the array from that position are deleted:

```
/**
* @customfunction
*/
function custom_function5() 
{

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scratch Pad");
  var currentCellRowIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  Logger.log("The values are " + currentCellRowIndex);
  var currentCellColumnIndex = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getColumn();
  Logger.log("The values are " + currentCellColumnIndex);
  var array1 = sheet.getRange(6, 2, currentCellRowIndex, 6).getValues();
  Logger.log("The array values are " + array1);
  var array2 = array1[currentCellRowIndex].splice(currentCellColumnIndex - 1, 6 - currentCellColumnIndex); 
  Logger.log("The array2 values are" + array2);

}
```

[Spreadsheet][1]

I'm getting the following error: ReferenceError: array1 is not defined
[1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0

Comment: From the code you posted, I can not see array1 defined anywhere, so this error seems expected. Is it defined above and not in you snippet?

Comment: Ooops! My bad. Will correct. Thanks a ton bud.

Comment: From the code you posted as well, it seems that you have defined SpreadsheetApp on variables `currentCellRowIndex` and `currentCellColumnIndex` without defining it's source sheet which would expectedly produce an error.

Comment: Can you also provide a sample expected output based on your provided sample sheet?

Comment: Doesn't the following first line of the function define the source spreadsheet: var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0');

Comment: Try using Array.filter() method

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED. Try this:**

```
  function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("B6:G13");
  var table = sheet.getValues();
  var startRow = 6; //define start row
  var startCol = 2; //define start col
  var arrayColPosition = ss.getColumn() - startCol;
  var arrayRowPosition = ss.getRow() - startRow;
  var trigger = false;

  console.log("Selection Column: "+arrayColPosition, "\nSelection Row: "+arrayRowPosition);

  var finalTable = table.map((r, i) => i == arrayRowPosition ? r.map((y, c) => c == arrayColPosition ? y[arrayColPosition] = '*' : y) : r);

  console.log(finalTable);

  var res = finalTable.map((r, indexRow) => r.map((c, indexColumn) => {
    if(c == '*') trigger = true;
    if(indexColumn >= arrayColPosition && trigger || indexRow > arrayRowPosition ){
      return '';
    }else{
      return c;
    }
  }));

  sheet.setValues(res);
}
```

The active cell will set a placeholder " * " and from there it will delete the remaining data on the table.

GIF:

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! That works. And I would never have thought to approach the solution from this perspective. Thanks that.